# Regex substring from last underscore occurrence till nth underscore (from the back)

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to subset a string from the back based on occurrence of underscores. Example follows:

```
string <- "trash_trash_trash_keep_keep_keep_trash.trash"
```

I am trying to substring from the last underscore till an nth occurrence. In this example, the desired output is:

```
"keep_keep_keep"
```

My attempt so far is messing up: `'^(?:[^_]*){3}(.+)_'` I think I should address the problem from the back, instead the start of the string.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: You didn't provide much in the way of rules, but if you wanted it backward...(using `dplyr` just for the pipe) `unlist(strsplit(string, "_")) %>% {rev(.)[2:4]} %>% paste0(., collapse = "_")` This assumes that there is always one underscore after the string you want to keep and always two underscores within the string to keep. If the words can vary (so it needs to be 'un-reversed', then just add another `rev()`: `unlist(strsplit(string, "_")) %>% {rev(.)[2:4]} %>% rev() %>% paste0(., collapse = "_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to @Kat's approach in the comment but using a function to make it dynamic.

```
string <- "trash_trash_trash_keep_keep_keep_trash.trash" 

return_last_n_words <- function(x, n) {
  strsplit(x, '_')[[1]] |> head(-1) |> tail(n) |> paste0(collapse = "_")
}

return_last_n_words(string, 3)
#[1] "keep_keep_keep"

return_last_n_words(string, 4)
#[1] "trash_keep_keep_keep"

return_last_n_words(string, 2)
#[1] "keep_keep"
```

The idea is to split the string by underscore (`_`), drop the last part, select last `n` words and paste it in one string.

Answer (score 2):

I think this `regex` should do. It uses both a positive and a negative lookaround to isolate the correct fragment:

```r
string <- "trash_trash_trash_keep_keep_keep_trash.trash" 

stringr::str_extract(string, "(?<=^([^_]{0,999}_){3}).+(?=_[^_]*$)")

# [1] "keep_keep_keep"
```

You can change the 3 in the regex, depending on how many underscores from the front you would like.